# how to create this background frame to the card using html and css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uJlK.png) how to create this card having this brown and yellow colored frame

thanks in advance

i tried with css border with this code but it is only creating brown part, i am not able to create yellow part of the frame

```
.card {
  background-color: var(--background);
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 30px) auto 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid var(--primary);
  box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--green);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it ok for you?

you can play with values in before and after, actually it's 5px around.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 30px) auto 0 auto;
}

.card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border-top: 5px solid brown;
  border-left: 5px solid brown;
}

.card::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```